# How do I make urxvt render xft fonts?

Tags: command-line, font-rendering

I wonder whether there's a way to make urxvt render xft fonts:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Droid Sans Mono Slashed:pixelsize=9:Regular
URxvt.boldFont: xft:Droid Sans Mono Slashed:pixelsize=9:Bold
URxvt.talicFont: xft:Droid Sans Mono Slashed:pixelsize=9:Italic
URxvt.bolditalicFont: xft:Droid Sans Mono Slashed:pixelsize=9:Bold:Italic
```

If I try this, I get something like:
[image]

So it scales pretty bad:

```
 ! Fonts
 Xft.dpi:        132
 Xft.antialias:  true
 Xft.rgba:       rgb
 Xft.hinting:    true
 Xft.autohint:  true
 Xft.hintstyle:  hintfull
```

I'm not sure whether this is one of the reaons. However I want antialias and that Droid. Is there any trick here?

Answer (score 14):

urxvt will use a default font if it cannot find the xft font name you specify. For example, the following will look like your screenshot:

```
urxvt -fn 'xft:foo'
```

To find out which xft fonts you have available, run:

```
fc-list
```

Here is how I run urxvt with the beautiful [Ubuntu Monospace](http://font.ubuntu.com/) font:

```
urxvt -fn "xft:Ubuntu Mono:pixelsize=14,style=regular"
```

Comment: does this work with unicode characters? i am having some problems with ttyp0, gohufont and this way of specifying fonts

Answer (score 1):

I got it just working with command line option "-letsp -1", see also

http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/how-make-urxvt-look-gnome-terminal/

Answer (score 1):

If I remember, the spacing was fixed by

```
URxvt*letterSpace: -2
```

This is my .Xresources:

```
Xft.dpi:                    96
Xft.antialias:              true
Xft.rgba:                   rgb
Xft.hinting:                true
Xft.hintstyle:              hintslight

URxvt.depth: 0

URxvt.intensityStyles:  false                                       
! Turn it on here... (then boldFont)
URxvt.allow_bold:       false                                        
URxvt.font:             xft:Ubuntu Mono:style=Regular:pixelsize=17
! ... but put this on Regular, else the ls output is overly fat
URxvt.boldFont:         xft:Ubuntu Mono:style=Bold:pixelsize=17  
URxvt.saveLines:        8192


! Fix font space
! any larger than -1 I dont like
URxvt*letterSpace: -2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my `.Xdefaults` and Droid Sans Mono looks great:

```
!-- Xft settings -- !
Xft.dpi:        96
Xft.antialias:  true
Xft.rgba:       rgb
Xft.hinting:    true
Xft.hintstyle:  hintslight

! -- Fonts -- !
URxvt.font:xft:droid sans mono slashed:medium:pixelsize=11
URxvt.boldFont:xft:droid sans mono slashed:medium:pixelsize=11
```

Comment: That's funny because both `Xft.rgba: rgb` (instead of `none`) and `Xft.hintstyle: hintslight` (and `hintfull`) trigger the described behavior for me. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189856/85186

Answer (score 0):

Please note that there's a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rxvt-unicode/+bug/309792) regarding letter spacing. There's a work-around, though, which was proposed in the bug discussion and which I repeated over at [unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/189856/85186) (in case you can't find it).